# Perform LU decomposition without pivoting in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

How can I implement the function `lu(A)` in MATLAB so that `L*U` is directly `A` and I also get the real `L` matrix?

When I use `[L,U] = lu(A)`, MATLAB doesn't give me the right `L` matrix.  When I use `[L,U,P]` = lu(A), I need to implement `P*A = L*U`, but I only want to multiply `L*U` to receive A.

Comment: So you want to input a matrix and have it return two matrices whose product is that matrix? Knowing only A, you want to return L and U, where LxU=A? There is no distinct answer here, because there are multiple combinations of L and U that could make A.

Comment: I want to implement lu(A) in a way where it gives me a real lower and upper triangular matrix and L*U=A.

Comment: "I only want to multiply L * U to receive A."  But `lu()` does this.  It's just that the `L` is  a permuted lower triangle.

Comment: Yeah and I need a real lower triangle... :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MATLAB's `lu` always performs pivoting by default.  If you had for example a diagonal coefficient that was equal to 0 when you tried to do the conventional LU decomposition algorithm, it will not work as the diagonal coefficients are required when performing the Gaussian elimination to create the upper triangular matrix `U` so you would get a divide by zero error.  Pivoting is required to ensure that the decomposition is stable.

However, if you can guarantee that the diagonal coefficients of your matrix are non-zero, it is very simple but you will have to write this on your own.  All you have to do is perform Gaussian elimination on the matrix and reduce the matrix into reduced echelon form.  The result reduced echelon form matrix is `U` while the coefficients required to remove the lower triangular part of `L` in Gaussian elimination would be placed in the lower triangular half to make `U`.

Something like this could work, assuming your matrix is stored in `A`.  Remember that I'm assuming a square matrix here.  The implementation of the non-pivoting LU decomposition algorithm is placed in a MATLAB function file called `lu_nopivot`:

```
function [L, U] = lu_nopivot(A)

n = size(A, 1); % Obtain number of rows (should equal number of columns)
L = eye(n); % Start L off as identity and populate the lower triangular half slowly
for k = 1 : n
    % For each row k, access columns from k+1 to the end and divide by
    % the diagonal coefficient at A(k ,k)
    L(k + 1 : n, k) = A(k + 1 : n, k) / A(k, k);

    % For each row k+1 to the end, perform Gaussian elimination
    % In the end, A will contain U
    for l = k + 1 : n
        A(l, :) = A(l, :) - L(l, k) * A(k, :);
    end
end
U = A;

end
```

As a running example, suppose we have the following 3 x 3 matrix:

```
>> rng(123)
>> A = randi(10, 3, 3)

A =

     7     6    10
     3     8     7
     3     5     5
```

Running the algorithm gives us:

```
>> [L,U] = lu_nopivot(A)

L =

    1.0000         0         0
    0.4286    1.0000         0
    0.4286    0.4474    1.0000   

U =

    7.0000    6.0000   10.0000
         0    5.4286    2.7143
         0         0   -0.5000
```

Multiplying `L` and `U` together gives:

```
>> L*U

ans =

     7     6    10
     3     8     7
     3     5     5
```

... which is the original matrix `A`.

Comment: Thanks, I already wrote this on my own...but isn't this also possible in some way with lu(A)?

Comment: @zer0kai No there isn't.  MATLAB always does it pivoted to ensure stability.  If you had for example a diagonal coefficient that was equal to 0, the algorithm will not work.  Pivoting is required to make sure the LU decomposition is stable.

Comment: @zer0kai As such, if you have already written an algorithm to perform LU decomposition without pivoting, then you're going to have to use that.  LU decomposition without pivoting is rarely seen in practice.  It's primarily used to introduced people to the idea of the technique, then the introduction builds by introducing pivoting.  Pivoting with LU is what is used the most often.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to make lu of a not square matrix?

Comment: @zer0kai http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186972/how-can-lu-factorization-be-used-in-non-square-matrix.  Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254234/lu-decomposition-of-rectangular-matrices

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider doing LDU decomposition instead of unpivoted LU. See, LU without pivoting is numerically unstable - even for matrices that are full rank and invertible. The simple algorithm provided above shows why - there is division by each diagonal element of the matrix involved. Thus, if there is a zero anywhere on the diagonal, decomposition fails, even though the matrix could still be non-singular.

Wikipedia talks a little about LDU decomposition here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#LDU_decomposition

without citing an algorithm. It cites the following textbook for proof of existence:

Horn, Roger A.; Johnson, Charles R. (1985), Matrix Analysis, Cambridge University Press, ISBN 978-0-521-38632-6. See Section 3.5.

LDU is guaranteed to exist (at least for an invertible matrix), it is numerically stable, and it is also unique (provided that both L and U are constrained to have unit elements on the diagonal).

Then, if for any reason "D" gets in your way, you can absorb the diagonal matrix D into either L (L:=L*D) or U (U:=D*U), or split it symmetrically between L and U (such as L:=L*sqrt(D) and U:=sqrt(D)*U), or however you want to do it. There is an infinite number of ways to split LDU into LU, and this is why LU decomposition is not unique.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this hack (though as already mentioned, you might lose numerical stability):

```
[L, U] = lu(sparse(A), 0)
```